# Lua print a nested table

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua, nested, lua-table

I have a table "weather". I insert weather conditions for a particular day.  I can't seem to write a function that prints the contents of "weather" (see below for things I've tried.

```
day = "Friday"
conditions = {"Sunny", "85", "windy"}
weather = {{}}    --nested table


for k, v in pairs(conditions) do     
    weather[day] = {[k]=v}  
end
```

I've tried two things to print the weather table and neither work.

```
for k, v in pairs(weather) do 
print(k, v)
end

---- Output ---
1       table: 0x2542ae0
Friday  table: 0x25431a0
```

This doesn't work either, but I thought it would

```
for k, v in pairs(weather) do 
    for l, w in pairs(v) do
    print(l, w)
    end
end

----Output----
3   windy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `weather[day]` in the first loop and so only the last value remains.

I think you want simply this, instead of that loop:

```
weather[day] = conditions
```